Role of thrust during take off
When a airliner takes off, it looks like after rotation and lift-off, the plane flies up in the air parallel to the length of its fuselage.
Assuming lift from the wings is the major force in taking off, that should not necessarily be the case. (E.g. during landing the fuselage is typical at an angle with the movement of the aircraft.)
So, I am wondering, is my observation wrong (i.e. do airplanes not take off parallel to their major axis)?
Or is the engine thrust a greater factor in taking off, since the thrust vector is by design always parallel to the fuselage.
Or, 3rd option, is the airplane designed such that the lift of the wings in the default take off configuration results in a parallel flight, e.g. because this is most efficient from aerodynamic POV?


Engine thrust a greater factor in take off ... most efficient from
aerodynamic point of view

Aircraft need to overcome drag with thrust in level flight.  When an aircraft climbs, it needs more thrust.
The easiest way to understand this is to point the aircraft/rocket in a 90 degree (vertical) climb.  The wing no longer helps at all, and thrust alone must match gravity plus drag from forward motion.
A winged aircraft in level flight needs much less thrust because the wing is far more efficient at creating lift to counteract gravity.
As the aircraft raises the nose to climb, the lift vector tilts away from vertical.  Vertical lift is lost by cosine degrees climb.  A 10 degree climb loses only 1.5 % of the vertical lift but requires 17 % (sine 10 degrees) more thrust to compensate in addition to thrust required to maintain airspeed.
One can see thrust requirement will increase as angle of climb increases.
In order to be most efficient from the aerodynamic point of view, the aircraft raises its nose a bit further than the line of flight to maintain its best angle of attack.  This is done in level flight, climbing, or descending.

the difference is the amount of thrust required to maintain that straight line of flight and AoA in all cases


This answer seems rather over-complicated/confusing compared to what the OP is asking.

@MikeB please see this question.  Much has been written about this subject at this site.  Perhaps you would like to contribute an answer as well.

The Angle of Attack, which is roughly the delta between the fuselage and the velocity vector, is on the order of 5-10 degrees shortly after takeoff. This difference from exact alignment of the vector and the fuselage would be hard to observe from any single fixed point, with the aircraft moving past the observer pretty rapidly, but it is real - and very important to the flight of the aircraft!

I think the reference line of angle of attack is usually the chord of the airfoil, which is not necessarily parallel with the fuselage. The difference is angle of incidence.

@jpa  Yes, but as a matter of providing a conceptual answer to the posted question, that distinction doesn't really illuminate what's involved in the difference between deck angle & the flight path vector. At a more advanced level, then angle of incidence becomes an essential part of the discussion.


Or, 3rd option, is the airplane designed such that the lift of the wings in the default take off configuration results in a parallel flight, e.g. because this is most efficient from aerodynamic POV?

This is your best guess so far, but not exactly how I would describe the attitude.
Landing Configuration and High AOA
Remember, airplanes almost always use a different wing configuration for landing.  Along with the extra lift and drag provided by flaps, there is a change in angle of attack and a corresponding change in the required pitch angle.  Because the angle of attack needs to be on the high side to maintain a low speed, the fuselage doesn't point downward unless full flaps are used.  On some airplanes the full flap range is not needed or even detrimental to manuevering, so in a sense there's an advantage to flying more nose up rather than "parellel" to the flight path.
Relative Wind During Climbout and Low AOA
Relative wind is tilted down (from the upward direction) during a climb, so even with a low angle of attack, the pitch angle is above the horizon and still close to the flight path angle.  For turbojet aircraft, the climbout profile involves increasing airspeed and making configuration changes that influence the needed pitch angle.  You might observe slight pitch changes during the initial climb because the acceleration and changes of configuration are changing the angle of attack and changing the rate of climb.  Those happen even in stable weather.

I think that the following picture (source) summarises in a simple way what happens in a climb:

The airplane is moving along the red line labelled with "Flight Path" and having an inclination $\theta$ in respect to the horizon. The wing (and the fuselage it's attached to) is a bit more sloped than $\theta$ by an angle $\alpha$, which is the angle of attack that it needs to generate enough lift to win the ($cos\theta$ part of the)  weight. By definition, lift is perpendicular to the flight path and drag is parallel. The thrust generated by the engine(s) is normally aligned with the "Fuselage Reference" and it therefore has a (very small i.e. proportional to $sin\theta$) upward component. That's actually all.

In addition to the fine answers above, aircraft normally take off into wind and so the flight vector relative to the ground will be steeper than the vector relative to the air - in an extreme case an aircraft might ascend vertically if the wind speed equals takeoff speed.  Typically though the wind speed might be 10-15kts and with a takeoff speed of 100kts or so the aircraft would indeed appear to fly at zero angle of attack.

GREAT QUESTION! Really shows that you're trying to understand the concepts in depth. Here's my attempt to give a simplified explanation of aircraft performance.
One of the golden sayings in aviation is:

ATTITUDE + POWER = PERFORMANCE

One thing to keep in mind is that lift is produced due to the airflow over and under the wings. Thrust produced by the engine and the attitude (which is how far above or below the horizon the nose is pointing) work together to give us a certain amount of airspeed (which translates to the amount of airflow over and under the wings) which gives us the desired performance.
At any given phase in flight, we are trying to achieve an optimal combination of power and attitude (and also airspeed). A light single engine C-172, for eg., will use full throttle and adjust the pitch to get an airspeed of 75-80 kts (depending on the specific model of 172) to get the best rate of climb.
The reason why you see the fuselage parallel to the direction of travel during climb is because the the angle of attack required for an acceptable climb performance happens to be at the pitch at or very close to the direction of travel. In theory (at least), you "could" climb with the nose pointed higher than the line along which you're travelling but it wouldn't be very efficient, at least for most planes.
Similarly for approach and landing, we are trying to achieve an optimal combination of speed, thrust and flaps configuration, etc., to have a rate of descent and airspeed that is stable for that aircraft. When we fly slow, we generally use a lower power setting and so we have to compensate for the reduced lift by pitching up - which is why for bigger airplanes you see the nose pointing slightly above the horizon even while descending towards the runway as they have to pitch up that much to compensate for the lower thrust. The equilibrium you have to maintain to be along that travel path is what's important here. Any more thrust and the rate of descent will reduce and if you pitch down to compensate for the increased lift your airspeed willincrease. We try to balance the energy and have a stable configuration.

True, but when you are  landing , you decrease gradually the speed on final, that alone will increase the AOA, then aerobrake,flying parallel to the runaway, visually the nose is upward, but when you take off the speed "is alive", increasing,  the aircraft become" clean "landing gear up, flaps up, no needed for much of Angle of Attack. Also the parallax have a great role in view on this instance.

The question was about taking off...
